# ggplot2: Heatmap Plotting, geom_text placement only in selected cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm using a heatmap to follow the attrition in my experiment and I would like to print some date information exclusively in the two first columns, but for some reason ggplot2 won't accept that many missing observations.

This is how my plot look at the moment (way to many dates).

Can anyone tell me how I can limit the geom_text to only the two first columns?

See blow for sample code.
[image: heatmap and facet_grid]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
require(reshape)

# create sample data
set.seed(666)
dfn <- data.frame(
Referral  = seq(as.Date("2007-01-15"), len= 26, by="23 day"),
VISIT01  = seq(as.Date("2008-06-15"), len= 24, by="15 day")[sample(30, 26)],
VISIT02  = seq(as.Date("2008-12-15"), len= 24, by="15 day")[sample(30, 26)],
VISIT03  = seq(as.Date("2009-01-01"), len= 24, by="15 day")[sample(30, 26)],
VISIT04  = seq(as.Date("2009-03-30"), len= 24, by="60 day")[sample(30, 26)],
VISIT05  = seq(as.Date("2010-11-30"), len= 24, by="6 day")[sample(30, 26)],
VISIT06  = seq(as.Date("2011-01-30"), len= 24, by="6 day")[sample(30, 26)],
Discharge = seq(as.Date("2012-03-30"), len= 24, by="30 day")[sample(30, 26)],
Patient  = factor(1:26, labels = LETTERS),
openCase  = rep(0:1, 100)[sample(100, 26)])

 # set today's data for cases that do not have an Discharge date
 dfn$Discharge[ is.na(dfn$Discharge) ] <- as.Date("2014-01-30")

 mdfn <- melt(dfn, id=c('Patient', 'openCase'), variable_name = "Visit")
 names(mdfn)[4] <- 'Year'

 # order data in mdfn by 'Referral' in dfn
 mdfn$Patient <- factor(mdfn$Patient,levels = (dfn$Patient[order(dfn$Referral)]),
 ordered = TRUE)

mdfn$Year2 <- ifelse(mdfn$Year != 0, 1, 0)
mdfn$Year2[ is.na(mdfn$Year) ] <- 0

mdfn$FWrap <- 'Core Measures'
mdfn$FWrap[mdfn$Visit == 'Referral'] <- 'Referral'
mdfn$FWrap[mdfn$Visit == 'VISIT05' | mdfn$Visit == 'VISIT06'] <- 'Optional Measures'
mdfn$FWrap[mdfn$Visit == 'Discharge'] <- 'Discharge'
mdfn$FWrap <- ordered(mdfn$FWrap, levels = c('Referral', 'Core Measures', 'Optional Measures', 'Discharge'))

base_size <- 9
m2 <- ggplot(mdfn, aes(Visit, Patient)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill = Year2), colour = "gray") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
m2 + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c    (0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
opts(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 330, hjust = 0,
colour = "grey50")) + facet_grid(~ FWrap, scales = "free", space="free") + 
geom_text(aes    (label=format(Year, "%b. %d, %Y")), size=3, colour='white')

# this is how I thought I could solve it.
mdfn$Yearlabel <- mdfn$Year
mdfn$Yearlabel[mdfn$Visit != 'Referral' & mdfn$Visit != 'VISIT01'] <- NA
# mdfn[,c(4,5,7,3)]

m2 <- ggplot(mdfn, aes(Visit, Patient)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill = Year2), colour = "gray") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
m2 + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c    (0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
opts(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 330, hjust = 0,
colour = "grey50")) + facet_grid(~ FWrap, scales = "free", space="free") + 
geom_text(aes    (label=format(Yearlabel, "%b. %d, %Y")), size=3, colour='white')
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the `data` argument of the `geom_text()` layer, and pass it the `subset()` of values that you want displayed?

Comment: @baptiste, thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. Would you mind showing my what you mean? I'm not pro enough to understand what you mean. Thanks, Eric

Comment: Subset the mdfn data frame: `mdfn2 = subset(mdfn, Visit == "Referral" | Visit == "VISIT01")`. mdfn2 is then the data frame to use in the `geom_text` layer. `geom_text(data = mdfn2, aes(Visit, Patient, label = ...))`.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt, thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
p = ggplot(mdfn, aes(Visit, Patient)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Year2), colour = "gray") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue") + 
  theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  opts(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = theme_blank(), 
       axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 330,
         hjust = 0, colour = "grey50")) + 
  facet_grid(~ FWrap, scales = "free", space="free") 

s = subset(mdfn, Visit %in% c("Referral","VISIT01"))
p + geom_text(aes(label=format(Year, "%b. %d, %Y")), data = s, 
              size=3, colour = 'white')
```